# performSegueWithIdentifier isn't working

Tags: iphone, ios, user-interface, segue

I have this code running when I tap a button:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"services" sender:self];
NSLog(@"ButtonClicked");
```

I can see the log message appearing each time I press the button but the **segue isn't activating**.

In my storyboard file I have a segue named *services*, that's the segue I want to activate.

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

---

**Edit**
The button is inside a tab bar controller, will that affect things?

Comment: How you are performing segue, I mean are you pushing or presenting it modally or something else?

Comment: I'm trying to do a simple push

Comment: And your source view controller is embedded in Navigation Controller?

Comment: Yes for push you need to embed your source view controller in navigation controller.You can do this as follows:select your source view controller, go to Editor and select Embed In -> Navigation Controller.

Comment: Yep, thanks, that worked. If you make an answer along those lines, I'll accept. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For push you need to embed your source view controller in navigation controller.You can do this as follows:

> Select your source view controller,  Go to Editor and select Embed In
>   -> Navigation Controller.